# New to NumPy, how to sort an ndarray (not with just integers)?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This is my first time working with arrays and I am new to python in general. I gave this my best go and was curious if someone could correct my mistake and let me know where I went wrong! Thank you

```
# Names of a group of students 
names = ['Alice', 'Edward', 'Timothy', 'James', 'Brandon', 'Mark']

# Age and graduation year of the above students
class_roster = [
    [22, 2021],
    [23, 2020],
    [21, 2021],
    [19, 2022],
    [24, 2020],
    [23, 2018]
]
```

I first thought, how would I go about retrieving names and class roster together?

I did:
names + class_roster

Then need to get the index of the oldest person in the roster and retrieve their name from the names list.

Referring to this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#calculation)

I tried: with "cant assign to operator" error

```
names + class_roster = ndarray

ndarray.ptp([axis, out])
```

After I get the above to output the oldest person and their name, how would I flip that around code-wise to reveal the name of the youngest person?

Answer (score 1):

Assigning works the other way around:

```
ndarray = names + class_roster
```

also note that you currently do not have any numpy arrays.
For your problem:

```
names = ['Alice', 'Edward', 'Timothy', 'James', 'Brandon', 'Mark']
class_roster = [
    [22, 2021],
    [23, 2020],
    [21, 2021],
    [19, 2022],
    [24, 2020],
    [23, 2018]
]

# combine names with class_roster
people = [ x for x in zip(names,class_roster)]

# search for oldest student
oldest_person = max(people,key=lambda x:x[1][0])[0]
print("the oldest person is ",oldest_person)

# search for the youngest student
youngest_person = min(people,key=lambda x:x[1][0])[0]
print("the youngest person is ",youngest_person)
```

Lastly, it is probably better the make a class person which has name and age as attributes.
Or you could keep track of all this information using the Pandas library.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use numpy, first declare your lists as arrays:

```
# Names of a group of students 
names = np.array(['Alice', 'Edward', 'Timothy', 'James', 'Brandon', 'Mark'])

# Age and graduation year of the above students
class_roster = np.array([
    [22, 2021],
    [23, 2020],
    [21, 2021],
    [19, 2022],
    [24, 2020],
    [23, 2018]
])
```

Use [numpy.argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get sorted indices from `class_roster`:

```
indx = np.argsort(class_roster[:, 0])
```

(If you're unfamiliar with this indexing, you may [read more](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) about it)

Finally, use these indices to sort your array `names`:

```
names[indx]

# array(['James', 'Timothy', 'Alice', 'Edward', 'Mark', 'Brandon'],
      dtype='<U7')
```

Note that I have avoided merging these arrays. If that's important to you, you might want to use [numpy.hstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
np.hstack([names[:, None], class_roster])

#array([['Alice', '22', '2021'],
       ['Edward', '23', '2020'],
       ['Timothy', '21', '2021'],
       ['James', '19', '2022'],
       ['Brandon', '24', '2020'],
       ['Mark', '23', '2018']], dtype='<U21')
```

With all that being said, for this particular application `pandas` might be a more suitable package to use, as @joostblack mentions. As you might notice, by merging, you convert the numpy array to a different type, and hence, not very helpful.